# AudioVideoCaptureDevice - always record video in landscape mode

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using a `AudioVideoCaptureDevice` to record videos on my windows mobile phone. Now I would like it to always record in landscape mode, regardless how I hold the phone. Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Silverlight (not Universal) and are using the `Windows.Phone.Media.Capture` APIs then you can probably set it using the [`SpecifiedCaptureOrientation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.phone.media.capture.knowncamerageneralproperties.specifiedcaptureorientation.aspx) extended property.

The `Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture` class used in Universal apps also supports different properties, but they are not part of the WinRT API. Some (but not all) of the properties on [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376629(v=vs.85).aspx) should work, but since the UUIDs themselves aren't published you'll have to do some spelunking with `mfuuid.lib`.

Comment: It looks like MF_MT_VIDEO_ROTATION might be `5D 46 80 C3 71 22 8C 42 9B 83 EC EA 3B 4A 85 C1` (based on dumpbin output).

Comment: I tried using the SpecifiedCaptureOrientation and the EncodeWithOrientation properties, but this just rotates the video. My goal is to really capture a video in landscape mode while I hold it vertically. Is that even possible, I mean technically speaken? Isn't the camera built in a way that you must hold the phone in landscape mode in order to capture such a wide range?